# How to manage data access for a single shiny app with authentication?

Tags: shiny, shiny-server, shinydashboard, shinybs

I have Tab 1 in my App and this Tab includes two more subtabs 
Tab 1:1 and Tab 1:2. 
I have users A, B & C who are accessing the Tab. But I want to give access to Tab 1:1 to user A only, Tab 1:2 to user B and access to the whole tab to user C.

Is there any solution to this?
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/NQDVO.png)

Comment: Could you post a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example) or what you have tried so far?